# AWS RDS SSL connection Error mysql2 in Redmine database yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds, redmine, mysql2

I have hosted redmine on AWS it was working properly, Suddenly last two days its showing error **We're sorry, but something went wrong.
The issue has been logged for investigation. Please try again later.**

I have checked apache2 server log, it shows `Error ID: 53a00391
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-ISPn8Y.html
  Message from application: SSL connection error: error:00000001:lib(0):func(0):reason(1) (Mysql2::Error)`

so i have updated AWS RDS Mysql SSL connection, RDS Mysql SSL connection working properly when i tried to connect through command

[image: Mysql connection through command]

**database.yml**

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: database
  u;sername: user
  password: ******
  host: *****.c8pm9vrrqq0w.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
  port: 3306
  sslverify: true
  sslmode: 'REQUIRED'
  sslca: /path/to/**.pem
```

Still i am getting same **SSL connection Error**

Could any one please help me to resolve this error.

Thanks

Comment: Have you rotated your ssl certs as needed on [5th march 2020](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL-certificate-rotation.html)?

Comment: @Marcin yes i did, That is the reason i can able to connect through Command. i attached screenshot

Comment: Have you restarted Redmine?

Answer (score 1):

Have you rotated the CA certificate for your RDS instance? All RDS CA certificates expired on March 5

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL-certificate-rotation.html

Comment: lol. upvote from me, as I though exactly same at the same time.